# Multiple Functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question, I'm a little new to JavaScript.  I am trying to make a webpage containing multiple functions, but only the first of the functions will be successful.  I searched on google and I only got results for calling multiple functions at once, but that is not what I am looking for.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function frogger()
            {
                document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML="Frogger <br />Description: Get
                    the frog to the islands at the top of the screen without falling into the water or
                    getting hit by cars. <br />Controls: Up arrow key to move forward, down arrow key to
                    move backward, left arrow key to move left, and right arrow key to move right.";
            }
            function clear()
            {
                document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML=" ";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="descriptions" style="{height:100;}">
        </div>
        <div class="game" onmouseover="frogger()" onmouseout="clear()">
            <a href="/arcade/frogger.html"><img border="0" src="http://ggmedia.site50.net
/pics/frogger.PNG" height="100" width="100" /><br />Frogger</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can't put linebreaks in strings like that.

Comment: Check your JS console to see the error.

Comment: You're using the style attribute incorrectly. Instead of `style="{height:100;}"` do `style="height:100;"`

Comment: also specify the units, `100%`? `100px`?

Comment: Another option would be to hide/show content rather than continually regenerate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already a function named `clear` in the `document` object. Name your function something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your string has line breaks, you can remove them or add a `\` to the end of each line

```
function frogger()
{
    document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML="Frogger <br />Description: Get\
the frog to the islands at the top of the screen without falling into the water or\
getting hit by cars. <br />Controls: Up arrow key to move forward, down arrow key to\
move backward, left arrow key to move left, and right arrow key to move right.";
}
```

​
Edit: If you change the name of the [`clear`](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/xrTAM/) function to say [`clearx`](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/xrTAM/1/) it works, weird.

Edit: Apparently there is a clear method in the document object

Comment: by adding `\`what will happen, will the above sentence will be turn into a single sentence?

Answer (score 2):

```
function frogger() {
    document.getElementById("descriptions").innerHTML="Frogger <br />Description: Get the frog to the islands at the top of the screen without falling into the water or getting hit by cars. <br />Controls: Up arrow key to move forward, down arrow key to move backward, left arrow key to move left, and right arrow key to move right.";
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd actually prefer to see line continuations or concats than a long-ass string, really.

Comment: @sachleen I've never seen the backward slash method for strings like that. Thanks. Does that method have a name?

Comment: I'll +1 anyway because strings with 5000+ characters per line are for the lords only to read.

Comment: @AndrewAnthonyGerst Line continuations.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `clear()` function to something else. I changed it to `clearDesc()` and it worked fine (after fixing the line break issue in the string). See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LfkV8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="game" onmouseover="frogger()" onmouseout="clearr()">mousee</div>
    <div id="descriptions"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var frogger = function () {
            this.innerHTML = ["Frogger <br />Description: Get}",
                    "the frog to the islands at the top of the screen without falling into the water or",
                    "getting hit by cars. <br />Controls: Up arrow key to move forward, down arrow key to",
                    "move backward, left arrow key to move left, and right arrow key to move right."].join('');
        }.bind(document.getElementById("descriptions"));
        //
        var clearr = function () {
            this.innerHTML = " ";
        }.bind(document.getElementById("descriptions"));

    </script>
```

Here is this code in a jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/gerst20051/6Neqv/